# Why didn't Regulus Black tell the Order of the Phoenix about Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter

R.A.B. clearly became disillusioned in Death Eatery, Voldemort serving etc… and tried to hurt Voldemort by destroying a Horcrux.

Why did he go about hurting Voldemort in such a particularly inefficient leverage-less way? Why not tell about Horcruxes (or get the one he stole) to Dumbledore?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe **Regulus didn't know that the Dark Lord had made more than one Horcrux**.

Think about it.

It is unprecedented to have more than one Horcruxes.  The Dark Lord doesn't talk about them even to the most trusted servants, and had hidden the other Horcruxes well.  Regulus had died long ago: certainly before the Dark Lord had risen again (as Sirius has already owned the family house at the end of Prisoner), and very likely before the Dark Lord had fallen.  He didn't see the Dark Lord rise again and hear the Dark Lord's statement saying “I, who have gone further than anybody along the path that leads to immortality”, which is the statement that has given Dumbledore a clue about multiple Horcruxes.  Regulus likely hadn't even lived when the killing curse has rebound on Harry.  He likely doesn't know about what's happened in the Chamber of Secret.  He certainly hasn't seen Nagini as a Horcrux, as that Horcrux was created only the summer after Harry's third year.  He certainly doesn't know about Riddle's conversation with Slughorn.  In short, Regulus didn't know about enough clues to guess that the Dark Lord had made more than one Horcrux.

Consider also the note Regulus wrote in the fake locket.  (Half-Blood Prince chapter 28, quoting just parts of it here.)

> *… it was I who discovered your secret. I have stolen the real Horcrux and intend to destroy it as soon as I can.  I face death in the hope that when you meet your match, you will be mortal once more.*

Regulus clearly knows what a Horcrux is and that the locket is a Horcrux. But “your secret” could refer to just one Horcrux, as the Dark Lord has certainly kept it secret that he had even one Horcrux.  The rest of the note is also consistent with believing that there's only a single Horcrux.

Comment: The crux of my question was not so much as to why he didn't tell the Order about MULTIPLE Horcruxes, but about the one he stole. It's a good answer but only addresses a part of the question

Comment: @DVK: Most importantly, RAB needed to do his sabotage in secret. If he told anyone, word could get back to Voldemort, who could simply make a replacement. RAB's work had to remain secret until, in his dying moment, Voldemort realized that his Horcrux had failed. The Order was infiltrated, and Voldemort had a spy with Dumbledore (who was a double-agent, but that's another matter), so RAB's desire for secrecy is well-justified. Secondarily, RAB would not have been sure of his conclusions or his success before his act, and he died in the act, so...

Answer (score 5):

Regulus hopes to protect his family. Therefore, he can have no ties to the Order of the Phoenix if his family is to avoid Voldemort's wrath. Remember, Voldemort and the Death Eaters treat "Blood Traitors" as harshly as they do "Mudbloods," and if LV finds out RAB has gone against him, he will immediately target the Black family.

He is also a Quidditch Seeker, and from what we know, Seekers like to act alone. The skills required of a Seeker are those of speed, cunning, agility, and independence. Harry has them; Draco has them; Ginny has them; Viktor has them; and perhaps Regulus does as well. Maybe that is why it is significant that RAB be a seeker (and also to parallel what the other side could look like). Harry has a bit of a Hero Complex (understandable) who feels he can't really depend on others and needs to save people constantly. RAB does not begin so nobly, but by the end, he's had a change of perspective and heart. So maybe he feels he needs to save others while doing his own thing; in fact, maybe it's not in his *makeup* (the one that lead him to be Seeker in the first place) to trust others--except under grave circumstances such as those requiring Kreacher to apparate out of the cave with the real Horcrux and to keep the secret from others (especially from his mother--perhaps, again, for her protection).

Comment: That about being seeker seems a bit far-fetched to me (certainly not _all_ seekers are mavericks except on the pitch – Cedric? Charlie? Cho? Even for Harry I find it not so convincing); but I agree that Regulus would probably avoid approaching the Order, even when he'd turned against Voldemort and reasoned that it would be a rational thing to do in order to help his defeat.